# How to replace the contents of a file after processing

Tags: java

Let's say that I have a TreeMap and I want to take all values for a key, make a file with these, pass the file to another process loop and do this for every map key, so I always have to use the same file but its content must be replaced every time for each key.

What I do is:

```
PrintWriter writeRatings = new PrintWriter("ratings.txt", "UTF-8");
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Rating>> ratings = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Rating>>();
-->
for(Integer clID:ratings.keySet()){
        ArrayList<Rating> ratingGroup = ratings.get(clID);
           for(Rating r:ratingGroup){
                witer.println(r.toString());
           }
 }
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

With this, I get a file with all the data for each map key. Can you suggest how can I get only the data from the current key each time in the file?

Comment: If you're passing data between processes you should consider using pipes or another IPC method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me was to include this line into the for loop in the position of the arrow in the main question post:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same file and just append lines to it, use a `FileWriter` and set the append mode to true

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("filename", true));
```

This will append lines to the file, instead of over writing the file. This way, different processes can use the same file and keep on adding new data to the file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I would rather want to replace the whole content each time with the new data. If I just set the append mode to false would it just replace the document content?

Comment: If that's the case, there's no need for the filewriter. Why does your code not work now?

Comment: Because what I get now is a file with all the data from the TreeMap. For example I get all the data for key=1 then it appends data for key=2 etc. What I'm looking for is to get the data for key=1 and then replace all the data in file with the values for key=2 etc.

Comment: What do you mean get the data for key 1? what do you want to do with that data? I know you want to write key 2. So why not just `get` key 2 instead of iterating through the map?

Comment: My goal is to create a file with the values for each key, which I will then pass to another piece of code for further processing. So instead of creating 1000 files (this is the number of my keys) I just want to replace the file contents each time after the process, so I would only have one single file.